# I can't connect MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

```
private void keepdata()
    {

        string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=databaserfid;Uid=root;Pwd=12345;";
        using (mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        using (cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                mcon.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connect");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Connect");
            }
        }
    }
```

this code i can't connect MySql

State show "closed"

no error list

i install mysql connector and add references Mysql.Data already

how to solve this problem? (I need state Open)

Comment: missing curly braces on first **"using"** statement

Comment: silly question, but just to clarify, do you have all the MySqlClient references? `using MySQL.Data.MySqlClient`

Comment: @Sunny When you use multiple `using` statements right after each other you don't need curly braces except for the last one if it has multiple statements (a using can be followed by either a single statement (including a `using`) or a code block)

Comment: the is check your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using is not properly braced. try the one below. I cannot test this though

```
private void keepdata()
{

 string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=databaserfid;Uid=root;Pwd=12345;";
 using (MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
 {   
    using (cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            mcon.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connect");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Connect");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case, wouldn't there be a compiler error?

Comment: i using already but can't

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code which you used. Just made little changes and it worked for me. Have a look at the below code :

```
private void keepdata()
{
    MySqlCommand cmd;

    string connString = "server=[Server_Name];database=[Database_Name];user id=[User_Id];pwd=[Password];default command timeout=30000";
    using (var mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                mcon.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connect");

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Connect");
            }
        }
        mcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using above reference
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

```
public static string con_str = "Server=localhost;Database=databaserfid;Username=root;Password=12345";
        static MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(con_str);
        public static MySqlConnection connection()
        {
            try
            {

            con.Open();

        }            
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        return con;
    }
```